# Mail merge error with outlook 2013 and MS CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-2013

I am using Windows 8 with Outlook 2013 client to connect to MS CRM 2011 (both CRM server and on roll up 14). When I try to do a email via mail merge say against an account I get the following error

E-mail cannot be sent because the specified sender does not have an e-mail address. Add an e-mail address to the sender and then try again.Do you want to send the e-mail? If you click Yes, the e-mail will be sent out, but no corresponding activity will be created in Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

What I have already done

1) Made sure that the email address of the MS CRM user which is being used to connect outlook client and MS CRM 2011 server has a valid primary email and the email is approved as well.

2) un-installed, reinstalled and synchronized Outlook 2013 client.

Any pointers, help, log locations that can help will be much appreciated.

Thanks
Dev

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Troubleshooting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2009/05/29/troubleshooting-the-microsoft-dynamics-crm-client-for-outlook.aspx) section from Microsoft. It has some helpful checks that might help narrow down your problem.